# Sample application using python-gdl

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to use python-gdl (python bindings for gdl library, which features some docking windows for gtk+2). Even the origianl C gdl itself is awfully documented; its python bindings seems very unstable. Could you suggest any sample program, written in python-gdl and working?

I've tried to use the one described  [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-devtools/2009-September/msg00002.html) and [here](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/gnome-python-extras/2.25.3/gdl__test_8py_source.html), but it would fail with ugly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gdl_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    item1 = gdl.DockItem('item1', 'Item 1', gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gdl.DOCK_ITEM_BEH_NORMAL)
TypeError: Gdl.DockItem.__init__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

The python bindings don't even seem to provide the constructor signatures: e.g.

```
>>> help(gdl.DockItem.__init__)
Help on wrapper_descriptor:

__init__(...)
    x.__init__(...) initializes x; see x.__class__.__doc__ for signature

>>> help(gdl.DockItem.__doc__)
no Python documentation found for "Object GdlDockItem\n\nSignals from GdlDockItem:\n  dock-drag-begin ()\n  dock-drag-motion (gint, gint)\n  dock-drag-end (gboolean)\n  selected ()\n\nProperties from GdlDockItem:\n  orientation -> GtkOrientation: Orientation\n
...more bloody mess here...
```

Is this project completely dead and just deceives naive programmers with false promises?